# Mathematica Precision

Tags: machine-precision

How can I set the output precision of the following statement to 10 decimal places?  I was looking through the documentation, and for some reason, all I could find was `Accuracy[]` or `Precision[]`.

```
f[x_] := E^Cos[x]
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Which, by default, evaluates to:

```
7.95493
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is all in the documentation: [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html), [guides to numerical precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html), [presentation of numbers using `NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html). Please at least make some effort with the documentation.

Comment: @Verbeia I was looking through the documentation, and for some reason, all I could find was `Accuracy[]` or `Precision[]` but nothing like what Artes mentioned.

Comment: It is helpful to mention this in your question, so we know what you've tried. Anyway, the [documentation for `Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Precision.html) links to the [tutorial I mentioned](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html) and to the [guide page that mentions `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NumericalEvaluationAndPrecision.html). It was all one click away.

Comment: Thank you Verbeia. I will keep this in mind!

Comment: It's notable that the documentation for `Precision` links only indirectly through the tutorials to `NumberForm`.  The direct links are only `Accuracy`, `RealExponent`, `N`, `Chop`, `SetPrecision`, `MachineNumberQ`, `MachinePrecision`, `PrecisionGoal`, `WorkingPrecision`, `ExactNumberQ`, `NumberMarks`.  IMO, it'a a lot to go trawling through when looking for this answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

> ```
>  7.95492652101285
> ```

Comment: Oh yeah! Just what I needed. Thank you, Artes!

Answer (score 12):

The number of digits displayed for machine reals can also be controlled via a setting in the preferences dialog. Under **Appearance > Formatting > Numbers**, change the value for **Number of digits displayed in output**:

```
In[4]:= f[x_] := E^Cos[x]
In[5]:= NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]

Out[5]= 7.954926521
```

Note that this doesn't affect arbitrary-precision numbers, which show the digits appropriate for their precisions (shown in these examples after the backticks):

```
In[6]:= 1.23456789`4

Out[6]= 1.235

In[7]:= 1.23456789`14

Out[7]= 1.2345678900000
```

Comment: This has a downside of cluttering your notebook. The solution of @Vitaliy Kaurov is better in this respect. It only produces the long form numbers, when required.

Answer (score 11):

If you just want "10 decimal places" - you already have them and more. *Mathematica* just **displays** shorter version. You get your answer on default with 16 significant digits, - use `NumberForm` to see it:

```
f[x_] := E^Cos[x]
NumberForm[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}], 100]
```

> ```
>  7.954926521012846
> ```

I intentionally exaggerated with 100 digit precision so you can see where the default digits are cut off. Also if SHIFT+ENTER (evaluate) your answer/number (output cell), you will see it again - your 16 digits appear in the input and shorten in the output:

```
In[1]:= 7.954926521012846`

Out[1]= 7.95493
```

Answer (score 2):

Use in the following way also.

```
 SetPrecision[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}], 15]
```