# How to display the value of a very small number instead of "0."

Tags: numerical-integration, display

I need to perform an integration. There is one particular value, which may be very small that is showing up as `0.`. Is there any command in *Mathematica* 9 that will give me the very small value instead of `0.`?

[image]

Comment: `Chop`, `Round`, `Floor`. But after re-reading I see you are using `NumberForm`. Why? Get rid of it unless you have some special (cosmetic) reason for using it.

Comment: isnt he asking how to *not* chop the result?

Comment: @george2079 you have a point! ARIJIT, while you get a display of `0.`, Mathematica still knows about the correct value, but does not display all digits. Can you post your code as code, not just as image? Then we should be able to help you more easily. This Q&A might give you a starting point: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results

Comment: Please post code that can be copied instead of images of code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that the values are very small, smaller than can be represented by a machine numbers.  Perhaps `NIntegrate` decides the answer is zero.  You can use arbitrary-precision numbers, which you can do with the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) option, to get nonzero values.

```
a2 = 525/10;
u = 2*i - 1/2;
u1 = u*Pi/2;
u2 = u1/a2;
u4 = -1/5^2;
Table[NIntegrate[
  BesselJ[2, 2 x] BesselJ[2, u2 x] x Exp[u4 x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 20], {i, 5}]
(*
  { 3.9132803101634619543*10^-153338638, 
   -2.8913652452626206553*10^-153338639, 
   -2.1189063245786547756*10^-153338638, 
   -3.8801006291402211574*10^-153338639, 
    1.5024724257794001238*10^-153338638}
*)
```

Comment: Wow 10^_1533...you have my vote

Comment: @ubpdqn Yeah, it's hard to imagine a number that small being used.

Answer (score 2):

I have interpreted this question as per george2079s comment. I think this may a case of "asking too much" but I defer to numerical experts.

Note:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   BesselJ[2, 2 x] BesselJ[2, us[[1]] x] x Exp[u4 x^2]], {x, 0, s}, 
  PlotRange -> {-0.003, 0.003}], {s, {5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50}}]
```

[image]

Then testing for small upper limits (noting failure of convergence methods). I rewrote the code (and hope I have not made a mistake):

```
a2 = 52.5;
u4 = -1/25;
us = # Pi/(2 a2) & /@ (2 #1 - 0.5 & /@ Range[5])
fun[y_, t_] := 
 NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, 2 x] BesselJ[2, y x] x Exp[u4 x^2], {x, 0, t}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 20]
```

Tabulating:

```
Grid[Quiet[{#2, fun[#1, #2]} & @@@ Tuples[ {us, Range[10, 50, 10]}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extended comment (this question will probably get closed as a duplicate in any case).

As a (presumably) new user the best way to wean yourself of procedural constructs like `For` is to begin using `Table`. There are other ways to do things in Mathematica but the transition from `For` to `Table` is probably the easiest and most intuitive to begin with.

[image]

In that code `Quiet` is used to suppress a warning about lack of convergence. Note that I changed `u4` to make it a real. `Chop` is used to treat very small numbers below a cut off -- in this case below `10^-7` as zero. You can also use functions like `Map`.

[image]

In both cases above I'm sticking with the way you have set up the problem rather than re-writing. Objective is to show alternatives to `For` keeping the body essentially the same.

Finally there is no need to use `Print` to get the output:

[image]