# Increasing number of decimal places with FixedPoint

Tags: numerics

I've tried:

```
In[169]:= newton3[x_] := N[1/2 (x + 3/x)];
FixedPointList[newton3, 1.0]

Out[170]= {1., 2., 1.75, 1.73214, 1.73205, 1.73205, 1.73205}
```

Of course:

```
In[164]:= N[Sqrt[3], 20]

Out[164]= 1.7320508075688772935
```

How do you use the FixedPointList to increase the number of decimal places?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not `FixedPointList` - the problem is that *Mathematica* by default doesn't display that many digits. Consider for example

```
FixedPoint[newton3, 1.0] // InputForm
```

which displays several more decimals. [Another option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results) is to increase `PrintPrecision`:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], PrintPrecision -> 10]
```

This increases the number of decimals shown for all values in the current notebook.

```
Style[FixedPoint[newton3, 1.0], PrintPrecision -> 10]
```

does the same for the particular expression.

Finally we may do the following to make sure the problem isn't with `FixedPoint`:

```
FixedPoint[newton3, 1.0] == Sqrt[3]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the number of digits in the solution by setting smaller the criterion for convergence through `SameTest`, as in:

```
FixedPointList[(# + 3/# )/2 &, 1`20, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 1*^-10 &)]


{1.0000000000000000000, 2.0000000000000000000, 1.7500000000000000000, \
1.7321428571428571429, 1.7320508100147275405, 1.7320508075688772953, \
1.7320508075688772935}
```