# How to paste matrix to website and Email?

Tags: matrix

I tried to copy matrix from Mathematica to website, only end up with lots of garabge like this:

```
\!\(
TagBox[GridBox[{
{"16", "2", "3", "13"},
{"5", "11", "10", "8"},
{"9", "7", "6", "12"},
{"4", "14", "15", "1"}
},
AutoDelete->False,
GridBoxItemSize->{
     "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
      "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
      "ItemsIndexed" -> {}}],
"Grid"]\)
```

Then I have to edit it manually. Sometimes I send math equations and matrices in Email. Is there a better way to paste matrix?

Comment: Hi Nick, I voted to close the question here, because I think it's about how to use the site thus belong to the meta site.

Comment: I presume that this is output from Mathematica.  If so, transform it to `InputForm` and copy that.

Comment: @Silvia Of course you have a point there. Since people use `Mathematica` frequently here, they deal with Matrix and post questions and answers much more often than the others. I guess somebody may have already had a solution here. Would you please keep it for a while?

Comment: @Nick I understand your point, and I myself would like to see the answers for it, too. But as the current phrase of your question (i.e. copy to *this site*), IMHO, it would fit the [meta site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com) better. And it may even get more attention there so you can receive nice answers like [this post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5/17). But again, if the main site is preferred, maybe the first sentence could be rephrased -- maybe something like "copy matrix from Mathematica as an `InputForm`"?

Comment: @Silvia You're right, and thank you for pointing me the example on the meta site. I edited the question - made it more general for paste matrix to website and email contents. I think maybe other people may face the same problem as well.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I tried `InputForm` after reading your comment. It is much easier to edit. Thank you.

Comment: What is your purpose of the copy/paste? Do you want to preserve the computability or the traditional math formula style appearance or both?

Comment: @Silvia As I see it the complication lies with *Mathematica* and not the Stack Exchange software, therefore I feel it is better here than on Meta.  I will not contravene a community migration however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I already retracted my vote after OP rephrased the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a grid like this:

```
x = NestList[RotateRight, {1.5, 2/3, Pi, 9/7`, "!"}, 5];

Grid[x]
```

It looks like this in the Front End:

[image]

The image above was produced by selecting the Cell bracket and choosing **File** > **Save Selection As...**.

If we use the Context Menu item **Copy As** > **Plain Text** we get:

```
1.5 2/3 \[Pi]   1.28571 !
!   1.5 2/3 \[Pi]   1.28571
1.28571 !   1.5 2/3 \[Pi]
\[Pi]   1.28571 !   1.5 2/3
2/3 \[Pi]   1.28571 !   1.5
1.5 2/3 \[Pi]   1.28571 !
```

Using [halirutan's toolbar](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/121) the `\[Pi]` are easily converted to `π`:

```
1.5 2/3 π   1.28571 !
!   1.5 2/3 π   1.28571
1.28571 !   1.5 2/3 π
π   1.28571 !   1.5 2/3
2/3 π   1.28571 !   1.5
1.5 2/3 π   1.28571 !
```

**Copy As** > **Input Text** results different things depending on what is selected.  If only the content of the grid is selected (e.g. quadruple-click) we get:

```
{
 {1.5, 2/3, \[Pi], 1.28571, "!"},
 {"!", 1.5, 2/3, \[Pi], 1.28571},
 {1.28571, "!", 1.5, 2/3, \[Pi]},
 {\[Pi], 1.28571, "!", 1.5, 2/3},
 {2/3, \[Pi], 1.28571, "!", 1.5},
 {1.5, 2/3, \[Pi], 1.28571, "!"}
}
```

This form is useful because it can be pasted back into *Mathematica*.

However if the entire grid is selected we get something a lot messier:

```
\!\(
TagBox[GridBox[{
{"1.5`", 
FractionBox["2", "3"], "\[Pi]", "1.2857142857142856`", "\<\"!\"\>"},
{"\<\"!\"\>", "1.5`", 
FractionBox["2", "3"], "\[Pi]", "1.2857142857142856`"},
{"1.2857142857142856`", "\<\"!\"\>", "1.5`", 
FractionBox["2", "3"], "\[Pi]"},
{"\[Pi]", "1.2857142857142856`", "\<\"!\"\>", "1.5`", 
FractionBox["2", "3"]},
{
FractionBox["2", "3"], "\[Pi]", "1.2857142857142856`", "\<\"!\"\>", "1.5`"},
{"1.5`", 
FractionBox["2", "3"], "\[Pi]", "1.2857142857142856`", "\<\"!\"\>"}
},
AutoDelete->False,
GridBoxItemSize->{
     "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}, 
      "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, "ItemsIndexed" -> {}}],
"Grid"]\)
```

Another option is **Copy As** > **LaTeX** and then pasting the expression between `$` symbols, to yield:

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1.5 & \frac{2}{3} & \pi  & 1.28571 & ! \\
 ! & 1.5 & \frac{2}{3} & \pi  & 1.28571 \\
 1.28571 & ! & 1.5 & \frac{2}{3} & \pi  \\
 \pi  & 1.28571 & ! & 1.5 & \frac{2}{3} \\
 \frac{2}{3} & \pi  & 1.28571 & ! & 1.5 \\
 1.5 & \frac{2}{3} & \pi  & 1.28571 & ! \\
\end{array}$

This is visually pleasing but slow to render, and it cannot be easily pasted back into *Mathematica*.

Finally we can use [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) or [`ExportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString.html) to export in any supported format:

```
ExportString[x, "TSV"]
```

And **Copy As** > **Plain Text**:

```
1.5 2/3 Pi  1.2857142857142856  !
!   1.5 2/3 Pi  1.2857142857142856
1.2857142857142856  !   1.5 2/3 Pi
Pi  1.2857142857142856  !   1.5 2/3
2/3 Pi  1.2857142857142856  !   1.5
1.5 2/3 Pi  1.2857142857142856  !
```

Note that the Real numbers are printed here with full precision rather than [being truncated.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanatin. I'll use `Copy As > Input Text` for SE, since it can paste back to Mathematica. I'm wondering if you also have any recommendation on matrix/equation in email content?

Comment: @Nick I am glad that what I wrote you found useful.  How would the email situation be different?  Is the audience different, are the formatting tools different, or something else?

Comment: Well, in Email, I'd just need the best looking -- traditional style just like in math textbooks. There're already some Gmail+TeX/MathML solution; however, I use hotmail. Currently, I'm using a thirdparty online latex editor.http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php I'm wondering maybe there're better solution?