# Showing all Digits

Tags: output-formatting

What is the simplest method to display all digits by adjusting this code?

```
t = Table[1 + 10^(-n), {n, 1, 10}] // TableForm
```

Output:

1.1

1.01

1.001

1.0001

1.00001

1.

1.

1.

1.

1.

Comment: Without `N[]`, exact input will always yield exact output (in this case, fractions). With `N[]`, at `MachinePrecision`, you can use `InputForm[]` to see digits; for other precision settings, you should see them in full.

Comment: `Table[N[1 + 10^(-n), n + 1], {n, 1, 30}]`  ( a bit specialized to the specific example, but that's what you asked.. )

Comment: Possibly related or duplicate: [(3736)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: George's answer is perfect as I want to produce a table showing $\lim\limits_{t\to1}\frac{h(t)-h(1)}{t-1}=56.34$ for students being introduced to finding the derivative of $h(t)=58t-0.83t^2$ for the first time. By the way, thanks for your comment on disabling the Suggestions bar.

Comment: @george2079 I am reopening this; please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example problem, you know `1+10^(-n)` will have exactly `n` digits after the decimal, or `n+1` digits precision, so you can do:

```
  Table[N[1 + 10^(-n), n + 1], {n, 1, 30}]
```

> 1.1 , 1.01 , 1.001 , .... 1.000000000000000000000000000001

The example in the comment is something like this:

```
 h[t_] = 58 t - 83/100 t^2;
 Table[With[{t = 1 + 10^(-n) }, 
    N[ (h[ t] - h[1] )/(t - 1)  , n + 4]], {n, 1, 15}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

where the exact answer is  `N[ D[h[t], t] /. t -> 1  ] (* 56.34 *)`