# Suppress trailing 0s in numerical values

Tags: numerics, output-formatting, numerical-value

For example, this is what I want

```
In[1]:= N[Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}]]
Out[1]= {1.41421, 2., 2.82843, 4.}
```

But if I want a few more digits only from the irrational values, I get this

```
In[2]:= N[Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}], 10]
Out[2]= {1.414213562, 2.000000000, 2.828427125, 4.000000000}
```

When I want

```
Out[2]= {1.414213562, 2., 2.828427125, 4.}
```

In the first case, it detects that 4^(1/2) is exactly 2, and intelligently suppresses the trailing zeros, giving `2.`, but in the second case it doesn't. I'd like to be able to request more digits when necessary, but still suppress trailing zeros.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other answers have provided solutions but they have not directly addressed why this happens.  The use of [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) on exact values with a numeric second parameter (e.g. `10`) produces arbitrary-precision output, and these values are by default displayed in full without truncation.

Compare:

```
5.000000   (* machine precision Real *)
5`7        (* arbitrary precision *)
```

> ```
> 5.
>
> 5.000000
> ```

The methods in Alan's and Michael's answers get around this by converting to machine precision and then adjusting output.  However if you want to print more than [`$MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachinePrecision.html) digits these will not work.  Carl's answer comes closer but it also has a problem in that *more* digits than requested may be printed.

If you specifically want to suppress trailing zeros then you could process to affect that.

For whole numbers simply:

```
rep = r_Real /; r == Round[r] :> N @ Round[r];

N[Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}], 25] /. rep
```

> ```
> {
>  1.414213562373095048801689,
>  2.,
>  2.828427124746190097603377,
>  4.
> }
> ```

If you need to preserve the arbitrary precision nature of the output when used as input use [`Interpretation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpretation.html):

```
rep2 = r_Real /; r == Round[r] :> Interpretation[N @ Round[r], r];
```

If you want to trim trailing zeros that are not immediately following the decimal point you might turn to string processing:

```
rep3 = r_Real :> 
   Interpretation[
    RawBoxes @ StringReplace[ToString[r], 
      Shortest[x__] ~~ "0" .. ~~ EndOfString :> x], r];

N[Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}]/10, 25] /. rep3 // Column
```

> ```
> 0.1414213562373095048801689
> 0.2
> 0.2828427124746190097603377
> 0.4
> ```

If you want to do this globally for a session consider [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html), e.g.

```
$PrePrint = # /. rep3 &;
```

Then you can simply write:

```
N[Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}]/10, 10]
```

Comment: This is quite comprehensive. And I especially liked the idea of adding this to `$PrePrint`

Answer (score 4):

```
NumberForm[N@Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}], 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a form that displays numbers the way you want:

```
MakeBoxes[SuppressedZeroForm[a_], StandardForm] ^:= MakeBoxes[
    Defer[InputForm[a, NumberMarks -> False]]
]
```

For example:

```
N[Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}], 10] //SuppressedZeroForm
```

> {1.4142135624, 2., 2.8284271247, 4.}

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results/3752#3752) to [Annoying display truncation of numerical results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results):

```
Style[N@Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}], PrintPrecision -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And adapting [the accepted answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results/3737#3737), we essentially get Alan's method:

```
NumberForm[#, 10] &@ N@ Table[4^(i/4), {i, 1, 4}]
```