# Precision in mathematica

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I am having some trouble with mathematica, i need to precise calculations and he is rounding my numbers and taking decimal cases from them and i wanted to know if there's a way i can tell him to stop or only do that for some specific lenght of numbers, for example if we have $0.0119935,0.0561,0,084942$ and add them up the result should be $0,1530355$ and mathematica gives me $0.153036$. Is there a way i can change this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `expr = 0.0119935 + 0.0561 + 0.084942` **displays** as

`0.153036`

The output display (menu: Mathematica | Preferences | Displayed precision) is rounded to six (default) decimal places; however, the internal value is not rounded. To see the internal value look at the `FullForm`: 

`expr // FullForm` displays as 

`0.1530355\``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annoying display truncation of numerical results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve this issue by using [`SetPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html).

I hope that helps!