# How are Accuracy and Precision related Mathematica for a given operation?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision, guidelines

The common understanding for *Accuracy* and *Precision* in English language is given by this figure.
[image]

Inspired by [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156099/10397) I have a follow up question relating [`Accuracy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html) and [`Precision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) in *Mathematica* and Wolfram language.

**How do we understand the relationship between `Accuracy` and `Precision` in the following example?**

```
Accuracy[
 SetPrecision[
  SetAccuracy[
   12.3
   , 20], 15]
 ]
```

> ```
> 13.9101
> ```

```
Precision[
 SetAccuracy[
  SetPrecision[
   12.3
   , 20], 15]
 ]
```

> ```
> 16.0899
> ```

Where is this 13.9101 and 16.0899 coming from, exactly.

---

Given an operation, such as [`Subtract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subtract.html), [`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html) or [`Times`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html).

**How do we predict the  `Accuracy` and `Precision` of the outcome?**

```
Precision[
 Times[
  SetPrecision[10, 3] ,
  SetPrecision[1, 7]
  ]]
```

> ```
> 2.99996
> ```

```
Precision[
 Plus[
  SetPrecision[10, 3] ,
  SetPrecision[1, 7]
  ]]
```

> ```
> 3.04139
> ```

```
Accuracy[
 Plus[
  SetAccuracy[10, 3] ,
  SetAccuracy[1, 7]
  ]]
```

> ```
> 2.99996
> ```

```
Accuracy[
 Times[
  SetAccuracy[10, 3] ,
  SetAccuracy[1, 7]
  ]]
```

> ```
> 2.99957
> ```

Comment: Given an approximate number nonzero number `x` with an uncertainty `dx`, then according to the docs, `Accuracy[x]`, `Precision[x]` and `dx` are related as follows: `Accuracy` is `-Log[10,dx]` and `Precision` is `-Log[10,dx/x]`.  Propagated error is computed according to the usual rules, I think.

Comment: Look up [`RealExponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealExponent). [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy) and [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision) are not independent, and their relationship depends on the size of the number. Since they are not independent, it makes no sense to stack them as you suggest in your comment above.

Comment: The uncertainty `dx` is the same, whether determined from `Accuracy` or `Precision`, no?

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should have said "Given a number `x` with a given precision, then the accuracy, precision and uncertainty `dx` are related as follows...."  In the internal representation of nonzero real numbers, it is the precision that is stored or specified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Precision is the principal representation of numerical error

Except for numbers that are equal to zero, error in arbitrary-precision numbers is stored internally as its precision.  For numbers equal to zero, the accuracy is stored, because the precision turns out to be undefined (even if `Precision[zero]` is defined).  One way to view zeros are as a form of `Underflow[]` for arbitrary precision numbers, which I will explain below.

For a nonzero number $x$ with precision $p$, the error bound $dx>0$ and accuracy $a$, as defined by [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) and [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html), are related as follows:
$$ p = - \log_{10} |dx / x| \,, \quad a = - \log_{10} dx\,.\tag{1}$$
An arbitrary-precision number $x$ represents a real number $x^*$ in the interval
$$ x - dx < x^* < x + dx\,.$$

For zero numbers, the precision formula $ p = - \log_{10} |dx / x|$ is undefined; however the `Precision` of a zero is defined to be `0.` in *Mathematica*, which is the lowest allowed setting of 
[`$MinPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MinPrecision.html).
Further explanation of zeros shows why there is this limit.

An arbitrary-precision zero is stored with its accuracy $a = - \log_{10} dx$.
It represents a number $x^*$ in the interval 
$$-dx < x^* < dx \,.$$
When a computation results in $dx \ge |x|$, the result is a zero with `Accuracy` $a=-\log_{10}dx$.  In this sense the zero represents an underflow. The limiting value $dx = |x|$ corresponds to a precision of $p = - \log_{10}|dx/x| = 0$.  Defining the `Precision` of a zero to be `0.` is consistent with this.

The function [`RealExponent[x]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealExponent.html) provides another way to express a connection between precision and accuracy, although in my opinion it is not the fundamental idea. When $x$ is nonzero, `RealExponent[x]` is simply $\log_{10} |x|$ and is related to precision and accuracy by
`RealExponent[x] = Precision[x] - Accuracy[x]`, which follows from equations (1) above. This relationship holds for zeros, too, and simplifies to `RealExponent[zero] = -Accuracy[zero]`. This can be taken as the definition of `RealExponent[x]` in terms of `Precision[x]` and `Accuracy[x]`.

#### Error propagation and an example in the OP

It turns out that arbitrary precision numbers use a linearized model of error propagation.

```
(* Compute the uncertainty/error bound  d[x]  in a number  x  *)
ClearAll[d];
d[x_ /; x == 0] := 10^-Accuracy[x];
d[x_?NumericQ] := x*10^-Precision[x];
```

As @rhermans shows, the propagated error in multiplication is given by

```
(x + d[x]) (y + d[y]) - x y // Expand
(*  y d[x] + x d[y] + d[x] d[y]  *)
```

However, the computed `Accuracy` of a product more closely agrees with the linear part `y d[x] + x d[y]` with the quadratic term `d[x] d[y]` dropped.  Here is a comparison of the linear and full model on the OP's example:

```
Block[{x = SetAccuracy[10, 3], y = SetAccuracy[1, 7]},
  {y*d[x] + x*d[y], y*d[x] + x*d[y] + d[x] d[y]}
  ];
-Log10[%] - Accuracy[Times[SetAccuracy[10, 3], SetAccuracy[1, 7]]]
(* 
  { 4.44089*10^-16,  <-- linear model off by 1 bit (ulp)
   -4.33861*10^-8}
 *)
```

Presumably this is done for efficiency and justified on the grounds that in a floating-point model, the term `d[x] d[y]` would be less than the FP epsilon and rounded off.

#### The composition of `SetAccuracy` and `SetPrecision` (OP's first examples)

Both `SetAccuracy` and `SetPrecision` set or reset the uncertainty/error bound of a number `x`, which is stored as the precision or accuracy according as `x` is nonzero or zero, respectively.  So the first example turns out to be the accuracy of the number `` x = 12.3`15 `` with precision `15.`:

```
Accuracy[12.3`15]
(*  13.9101  *)
```

Note the special case: `SetPrecision[zero, prec]` yields an exact `0` if `zero == 0`.

#### Unexpected result adding approximate zero

I do not understand how the point-estimate is derived for the last two and why it is less than `10^-9`, `10^-8` respectively:

```
accEx = {  (* add a zero with d[x] == 10^-10 to various numbers *)
   0``10 + 10^-11,   (* d[x] > x *)
   0``10 + 10^-10,   (* d[x] == x *)
   0``10 + 10^-9,    (* d[x] < x *)
   0``10 + 10^-8};   (* d[x] < x *)
FullForm /@ accEx
(*
  {0``10.,
   0``10.,
   9.9999999996153512982210997961`0.9999999999832958*^-10,  Expected 1.`1.*^-9
   9.99999999999482205859102634804`2.*^-9}                  Expected 1.`2.*^-8
*)
```

The accuracy is preserved and the differences from the expected values are zero according to the precision, but it would also have turned so with the expected values:

```
Accuracy /@ accEx
(*  {10., 10., 10., 10., 10.}  *)

accEx - 10^Range[-11, -7]
(*  {0.*10^-10, 0.*10^-10, 0.*10^-10, 0.*10^-10, 0.*10^-10}  *)
```

#### Function example

The linearized model of `y = f[x]` is `d[y] = f'[x] d[x]`:

```
Sqrt[2.`20] // FullForm
(*  1.41421356237309504880168872420969807857`20.30102999566398  *)
```

The precision is `20.30102999566398`, because `f'[x] = 1/(2 Sqrt[x])` effectively adds `Log10[2]` to the precision:

```
Sqrt[2.`20] // Precision // FullForm
(*  20.30102999566398`  *)

-Log10[
  (1/(2 Sqrt[2.]) * 2.*10^-20) / Sqrt[2.]  (* d[y] / y *)
  ]
(*  20.30102999566398` *)

20. + Log10[2]
(*  20.30102999566398`   *)
```

Comment: Regarding section "Unexpected result adding approximate zero": both version 5.2 and 8.0.4 give what you call the *expected result*. Probably worth to report current behavior as an indication of potential bug.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for letting me know. The change seems to have been introduced in 11.1.0 or 11.1.1.  11.0.0 gives the "expected" result.

Comment: This is excellent. I have [another follow-up question regarding your *Error propagation* section](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156481/10397)

Comment: Something seems incorrect in your answer. According to the Doc(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html)  "The Wolfram Language is set up so that if a number  has uncertainty δ , then its true value can lie anywhere in an interval of size δ  from x-δ/2 to x+δ/2. " Shouldn't the dx in  −<∗<+ be dx/2 ?

Comment: @MurphyNg You're probably right, but how would you verify that the docs accurately describe the behavior of M/WL? Take the example `x = N[Pi^10, 30]; dx = x*10^-SetPrecision[Precision[x], Infinity];`. Then `{x, x + dx/3}` are *displayed* as different numbers, although the docs claim "Adding or subtracting a quantity smaller than the uncertainty has no visible effect." I wouldn't rely on display (`SetPrecision[{x, x + dx/3}, 32]` shows it's due to rounding). I think this is the best test: ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, x == x + dx]``, but it returns `True`. (Probably how I checked.)

Comment: Your example really shows that even official doc didn't correctly describe details of Mathematica. Actually, Squandering much time studying about many strange behavior in numeric precision,  I sort of aware these kinds of misdescription and lack of description are more than I imagine. Disappointing.

Comment: @MurphyNg Also, an "uncertainty" $\delta$ usually means $x \pm \delta$, not $x \pm \delta/2$. Confusion probably arises because in a discrete floating-point number system, if the numbers near a real number $x$ have a spacing $\epsilon$, then the best floating-point estimate of $x$ has an uncertainty $\delta = \epsilon/2$. The pitfall of remembering whether in this or that case to use the radius $\delta$ or the diameter $\epsilon$ of the interval leads to a somewhat common mistake. I'm inclined to think the docs are mistaken here.

Answer (score 8):

### `Accuracy` and `Precision` are related though [`RealExponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealExponent.html)

The relation between [`Accuracy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html) and [`Precision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) is given by

```
RealExponent[x] + Accuracy[x] == Precision[x]
```

Therefore, as `RealExponent[12.3]-> 1.08991` then `Accuracy[SetPrecision[12.3, 15]]` must be `15 - 1.08991 -> 13.9101`

Similarly, `Precision[SetAccuracy[12.3, 15]]` is `15 + 1.08991 -> 16.0899`.

### Operations

To get the `Accuracy` after an operation, we just need to distribute the errors.

The error of `Times[a, b]` is

```
ExpandAll[(a + δa) (b + δb) - a b]
```

> ```
>  b δa + a δb + δa δb
> ```

where `Accuracy[a] -> -Log10[δa]`.

### Numerical example

```
y = SetAccuracy[10, 3];
z = SetAccuracy[1, 7];
Accuracy[y z]
```

> ```
> 2.99957
> ```

```
N[-Log10[
    b δa + a δb + δa δb
    ]] /. {
  a -> y,
   b -> z,
  δa -> Power[10, -3],
  δb -> Power[10, -7]
  }
```

> ```
>  2.99957
> ```