# Mathematica 12.1: Evaluation result does not show decimals

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, arithmetic

It surprises me that Mathematica does not show decimals after evaluating the following calculations:

```
500000+5.05
```

Result: 500005.

Expecting: 500005.05

```
500000+5.65
```

Result: 500006.

Expecting: 500005.65

It is possible to use `FullForm[]` to see the decimals, but this seems redundant when working with smaller numbers and/or a few decimals.

Comment: You can use NumberForm on the result to specify display of more digits in a one-off approach, or you can set a different default permanently using Settings -> Appearance -> Formatting -> Numbers. See the two non-accepted answers to [Mathematica Precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3594/27951).

Comment: Thanks! Solved by changing to a higher value in: Edit->Preferences->Appearance->Formatting->Numbers, Displayed Precision, Number of digits displayed in output [change value]

Comment: Also a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24896/4999